# error module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments error in Python

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I have 3 classes: Nodo.py, Lista.py and ListaEnlazada.py

The code of Nodo is:

```
class Nodo:
def __init__(self, dato=None , nodo = None): #@Method
    self._dato = dato
    self._siguiente = nodo
def setDato(self, dato): #@Method
    self._dato = dato
def getDato(self): #@Method
    return self._dato
def setSiguiente(self,nodo): #@Method
    self._siguiente = nodo
def getSiguiente(self): #@Method
    return self._siguiente
```

The code of Lista is:

```
class Lista:        
def __init__(self): #@Method
    self._tamanio=0
def elemento(self,pos): #@Method
    pass
def agregar(self,elem,pos): #@Method
    pass
def eliminar(sel,pos): #@Method
    pass
```

Finally, the code of ListaEnlazada is:

```
import Nodo
import Lista

class ListaEnlazada(Lista):
def __init__(self): #@Method
    Lista.__init__(self)
    self.__inicio =  None
def esVacia(self): #@Method
    return self.__inicio == None        
def elemento(self,pos): #@Method
    pos = pos-1
    if(self.__inicio == None):
        return  None
    else:
        aux = self.__inicio
        while(aux.getSiguiente() != None and 0<=pos):
            aux = aux.getSiguiente()
            pos -=1
        return aux.getDato()    
def agregar(self,elem,pos): #@Method
    nuevo = Nodo(elem,None)
    if(self.__inicio == None):
        self.__inicio = nuevo
    else:
        aux = self.__inicio
        while(aux.getSiguiente() != None):
            aux = aux.getSiguiente()
        aux.setSiguiente(nuevo)
    self._tamanio +=1        
def eliminar(self,pos): #@Method
    cont = 0
    if(cont == pos):
        self.__inicio = self.__inicio.getSiguiente()
        self._tamanio -=1
    else:
        aux = self.__inicio
        while(True):
            cont += 1
            if(cont==pos):
                aux2 = aux.getSiguiente()
                aux.setSiguiente(aux2.getSiguiente())
                break
            aux = aux.getSiguiente()                
            if(pos<cont):
                print ("fuera de  rango")
```

When I compile ListaEnlazada y get the next error:

> TypeError: module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Which is the problem and how I can solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question and indent your code properly!

Answer (score 2):

You've named a module and a class the same thing, and you're trying to have a class inherit from a module instead of inheriting from the class the module contains.

Inherit from the class:

```
class ListaEnlazada(Lista.Lista):
    ...
```

and stop writing Python like it's Java. If you really want to stick every class in its own module, at least name the modules in lowercase, as is standard convention in Python. It's harder to mix up `lista` and `Lista` than to mix up `Lista` and a different `Lista`.